# Cmd to powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

Hello guys and sirs i need a powershell command of this cmd command is not working in powershell
Could anyone help me make this one as ps script?

```
cls
curl -LJOk "https://github.com/doktor83/SRBMiner-Multi/releases/download/0.8.9/SRBMiner-Multi-0-8-9-win64.zip"
tar -xvf SRBMiner-Multi-0-8-9-win64.zip
cd SRBMiner-Multi-0-8-9
SRBMiner-MULTI.exe --disable-gpu --algorithm verushash --pool eu.luckpool.net:3956 --wallet RTiE77wrw3oNc9Y5M99ckK5vvEppwErtg4.%RANDOM%
```

Comment: I suggest to remove the option `--verbose` (shorter `-v`, shortest just `v` in combination with other options like `-x` and `-f`) to make the extraction process faster, i.e. use just `-xf` instead of `-xvf`. The [tar manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html) describes really good when to use the option [verbose](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#verbose-tutorial) with examples. It makes really a difference on extracting thousands of files from an archive file if the option *verbose* is used or not on total time needed to accomplish the extraction process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a few tweaks are needed:

- `curl` -> `curl.exe`, to make sure that the executable by that name is invoked, rather than Windows PowerShell's (unfortunate) built-in `curl` *alias*, which refers to its `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet. (By contrast, there's no `tar` alias, so there's no strict need to use `tar.exe`, but it can't hurt.)
- `cd` is a built-in alias for PowerShell's [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location) cmdlet, which functions analogously to `cmd.exe`'s `cd` with a single, unquoted argument representing the target directory; so while you could retain `cd` as-is in this case, for a more PowerShell-idiomatic reformulation of your code `Set-Location -LiteralPath` is used below.
- `cmd.exe`'s dynamic `%RANDOM%` variable, which returns a random number between `0` and `32767`, must be emulated with a call to PowerShell's [`Get-Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-random) cmdlet, enclosed in `$(..)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), so that the cmdlet's output can be used inside an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings):

```
curl.exe -LJOk "https://github.com/doktor83/SRBMiner-Multi/releases/download/0.8.9/SRBMiner-Multi-0-8-9-win64.zip"
tar.exe -xvf SRBMiner-Multi-0-8-9-win64.zip
Set-Location -LiteralPath SRBMiner-Multi-0-8-9
SRBMiner-MULTI.exe --disable-gpu --algorithm verushash --pool eu.luckpool.net:3956 --wallet "RTiE77wrw3oNc9Y5M99ckK5vvEppwErtg4.$(Get-Random -Max 32767)"
```